# Prevent redeclare function Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make some "callback function" in case woocommerce plugin is not active because i need to implement conditions in the theme files and I need to use those functions, for example:

```
//calback functions if woocommerce plugin not active
if ( !in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) { 
if ( !function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) ) {
    function is_woocommerce() {
        return;
    }
  }
}
```

but I'm getting "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare is_woocommerce() previously declared in..." when trying to activate plugin.

Is there a way to prevent redeclare on this?

Comment: Can't you just use `if (function_exists('..')) { /* woocommerce code here */}` in your theme? Seems a bit too much to declare those functions

Comment: @kingkero I can but, I have to repeat that a lot, there are bunch of files in theme using that function, I thought it might be some prettier solution

Comment: `is_woocommerce` has a filter `is_woocommerce` too. Its better if you can achieve that into your condition.